# Are the classical moments consistently estimated from a single realization drawn from a given PSD?

Tags: estimators, consistency, spectral-analysis

Given a sequence $\{x_k\}_{k=-N}^{N}$ having power spectral density $S(f)$, we know that that "single realization PSD"

$$
\frac{\Delta t^2}{T} \left| \sum_{k=-N}^{N} x_n \exp(-2\pi i f n \Delta t) \right|^2
$$

is not a consistent estimator of the true PSD, which is defined as an expectation over this "single realization PSD" from difference sequences $\{x_k^{(j)}\}_{k=-N}^{N}$.

However, I now want to know what else is not consistently estimated. In particular, are the sample mean, variance, and skewness consistently estimated from a single realization, or do these also need to be averaged over realizations?

Comment: The use of orthogonal data tapers changes the situation. Slepian sequences, sine tapers, etc.. For the use of Slepians, see: Thomson, David J. "Spectrum estimation and harmonic analysis." Proceedings of the IEEE 70.9 (1982): 1055-1096.

Consistency is achieved (Slepian case) by keeping the main lobe width constant: increasing time series samples provides the use of more tapers and therefore the PSD estimator is the average of an increasing number of tapered estimates.